# How to handle a system.InvalidOperationException when converting from System.windows.FormsMessageBox to Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox

Tags: messagebox, xceed

I have a very bland messagebox asking my users a simple question (not yes or no). For quick development I used a simple System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox and worded the question ("If you want to choose 'A' click 'Yes' if you want to choose 'B' click 'No'"). Now I'm going back and improving the look and feel of my wpf application and I'm stuck trying to convert this MessageBox into something that looks good.

My preliminary search told me to use `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox` to be able to create custom message box but I'm getting an exception when I'm trying to use it.

Old Code

```
DialogResult dialogResultForDataDisplay = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Yes: Display by properties \n \t Each row will contain data for a specific asset class in a specific submarket during a specific quarter. \n \n No: Display by quarters \n \t Each row will will show the change over time for a specific property of an asset class in a specific submarket.", "Data Grouping Format", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

New Code

```
Style style = new Style();
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.YesButtonContentProperty, "By Property"));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.NoButtonContentProperty, "By Quarter"));
MessageBoxResult result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("How do you want your information displayed?", "My caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Yes, style);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The new code is generating this exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'`

How would you go about handling this exception?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found now is rapping it in an invoke method. If someone has a better solution please post.

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBoxResult.None;
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    Style style = new Style();
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.YesButtonContentProperty, "Yes, FTW!"));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.NoButtonContentProperty, "Omg, no"));
    result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("How do you want your information displayed?", "My caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Yes, style);
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```